# Is the class of power-associative binars finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: lo.logic, semigroups-and-monoids, universal-algebra

A binar is simply a set $S$ equipped with a single binary operation $*$. A power-associative binar is a binar where the subalgebra generated by a single element is associative. Equivalently, they can be axiomatized with the infinite set of equations, $\{(x*x)*x=x*(x*x), ... \}$. Is there some finite set of axioms in the signature $*$ that can axiomatize power-associativity?

Comment: I can think of some two variable identities that would imply power associativity, but would be strictly stronger.  Are you sure a finite basis exists?  Gerhard "Trying Not To Get Hyper" Paseman, 2020.06.06.

Comment: Try the following for a counterexample. Let an algebra be generated by x and have standard power arithmetic up to n.  Then, whenever two items have exponents which sum to a prime bigger than n, let the kth power times the jth power be equal to a symbolic term x to the power (k,j). In multiplying these, you can collapse the products as you like, as long as you keep (k,j) distinct from (j,k).  Gerhard "Always Look For Prime Examples" Paseman, 2020.06.06.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

Indeed, let $\mathcal{V}_n$ be the variety of magmas generated by the relating identities with variable $y$ saying that for every $k\le n$, all products of $k$ copies of $y$ are equal. Since the variety of power-associative magmas is $\bigcap_n \mathcal{V}_n$, a negative answer to the question is equivalent to showing that for every $n$ the relatively free magma $M_n$ on 1-generator $x$ in $\mathcal{V}_n$ is not associative.

Write by induction $x^1=x$, $x^k=xx^{k-1}$. I claim that in $M_n$ we have $x^{n+1}\neq x^nx$. Indeed, $x^nx$ can be rewritten in all ways $(ab)x$ with $a,b$ products of $k,\ell$ copies of $x$ (in some order) for $k+\ell=n$. No such $(ab)x$ is a relator, and no nontrivial relator has the form $(x=\dots)$. Hence $(ab)x$ can only be transformed by a relator substitution into another $(a'b')x$.

(This actually shows that $\mathcal{V}_{n+1}$ is properly contained in $\mathcal{V}_n$.)

Comment: In case it helps, here is a pedestrian definition of $M_k$. Let $J_1(x)$ be the free magma on 1 generator $x$ with chosen total order; enumerate pairs $(P_i,Q_i)$ of distinct elements of $J_1$ with $P_i<Q_i$ and $P_i,Q_i$ of the same size; choose the enumeration in increasing order of size, e.g. $P_0=x(xx)$, $Q_0=(xx)x$, $P_1=x(x(xx))$, $Q_1=(xx)(xx)$, $P_2=(xx)(xx)$, $Q_2=((xx)x)x$, etc. Write $i_n=\max\{i:|P_i|\le n\}$.Then $M_n$ is the quotient of $J_1$ by the magma equivalence relation (= quotient inherits magma stricture) generated by $P_i(z)=Q_i(z)$ for all $z\in J_1$.

Comment: In the comment, you should add "...for $i\leqslant i_n$", right?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, sorry, of course this why I introduced $i_n$.

Comment: Also in the answer, where you write "...is not associative", you actually need stronger statement "...is not power-associative", right? I believe this was part of the objection of @user158834

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე no it's correct (and correcting as you're suggesting would be correct too): for a 1-generated magma, associative and power-associative are the same by definition. I understand user158834's objection as understanding that $M_n$ is defined as the magma with finite presentation: 1 generator $x$, and, as relators, all associative relations of length $\le n$ w.r.t. $x$ (instead of taking also substitutions using these relations).

Comment: PS: the answer by user158834 was downvoted because of its initial tone, but what remains of it now is very interesting information.

Comment: It seems like you proved that there is no finite set of relations *in one variable* which characterize the power-associative magmas (because all such relations are necessarily reassociations, which are contained among the $\mathcal V_n$ relations), but there is still some work to be done to show that using more variables doesn't help. For example $((xx)x)y=(x(xx))y$ is also true in all power-associative magmas so it could conceivably be part of a basis.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I don't follow your point. The notion of variety encompasses equalities with an arbitrary number of variables, and in particular $((xx)x)y=(x(xx))y$ is an equality of $\mathcal{V}_n$ for all $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Obviously my example relation is derivable for $n\ge 3$ (and I would be hard pressed to come up with an example that is not like this since I believe the theorem to be true), but as you defined it that relation is not literally contained among the specified finite set of relations used to define $\mathcal V_n$ for any $n$, and I don't see how you exclude the possibility that all the infinitely many basis relations follow from some relation on 2 or 3 variables, plus some 1 variable associativity assumptions from some $\mathcal V_n$.

Comment: Suppose I have a finite set of relations $R$ involving possibly multiple variables, and I take $n$ to be bigger than everything about $R$ (sum of number of symbols or something). It seems to be an implicit part of your argument that $\mathcal V_n\subseteq\mathcal V_R$, where $\mathcal V_R$ is the variety of magmas satisfying the relations $R$. To prove this we would need to show that each relation in $R$ follows from power-associations of $x^i$ for $i\le n$. In the example you can factor out the $(xx)x=x(xx)$ part but I don't see how to conclude this is always possible.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro If there's an implicit part, let me write it in the following more precise way. If you have an arbitrary sequence of magma varieties $V_n$ with $V_n\supset V_{n+1}$, define $V_\infty=\bigcap V_n$ and if $F$ is any finite set of identities of $V_\infty$, then there exists $n$ such that $F$ is a set of identities in $V_n$. (Indeed if $V_*(m)\subset F_m\times F_m$ is the set of relations in $m$ variables, $F_m$ free magma, then $V_\infty(m)=\bigcup_n V_n(m)$, ascending union.)

Comment: I see it now. The "$n$ large enough" here is based on the least $n$ which proves the relations, which we know must exist by compactness (applied to provability of each relation in $V_\infty$). Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The question has been answered, but I will add some remarks
about magma/groupoid/binar. This is in response to some
of the comments on this page:

---

What you can currently read on the English Wikipedia:

The term *groupoid* was introduced in 1927 by Heinrich Brandt
describing his Brandt groupoid (translated from the German Gruppoid).
The term was then appropriated by B. A. Hausmann and Øystein Ore (1937)
in the sense (of a set with a binary operation) used in this article.
…
The term *magma* was used by Serre [Lie Algebras and Lie Groups, 1965].
It also appears in Bourbaki's Éléments de mathématique, Algèbre,
chapitres 1 à 3, 1970.

What you can currently read on the French Wikipedia:

L'ancienne appellation « groupoïde de Ore », introduite par Bernard Hausmann et Øystein Ore en 1937 et parfois utilisée jusque dans les années 1960, est aujourd'hui à éviter, l'usage du terme groupoïde étant aujourd'hui réservé à la théorie des catégories, où il signifie autre chose.
**[The old name *groupoïde de Ore*, introduced by Bernard Hausmann and Øystein Ore in 1937 and sometimes used until the 1960s, is to be avoided today, the use of the term groupoid being today reserved for category theory, where it means something else.]**

What is currently not on either Wikipedia:

A. (magma)
Peter Shor of MIT [has speculated](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63229) that *magma* 
might have been introduced
as a pun on Ore's name.
To distinguish a *groupoid in the sense of Ore*
from a *groupoid in the sense of
Brandt*, the phrase *groupoid of Ore* was used first,
then shortened to
*magma*, which in geology means a pile of molten ore.

B. (binar)
In June 1993, there was a conference at MSRI on
Universal Algebra and Category Theory 
organized by Ralph McKenzie and Saunders Mac Lane.
At this conference, there was a discussion session where
several topics were discussed, including whether there
could be general agreement on the future
use of the word *groupoid*.
At this discussion session, George Bergman of
Berkeley proposed using *binar* to mean an algebraic structure
with a single binary operation. (He also proposed
*unar* for an algebraic structure with a 
single unary operation.) It seemed to me that
Bergman thought this up on the spot, so it is plausible
that he is the source of *binar*.

Comment: I recall remarking to George Bergman around that time that there was a previous usage, from Star Trek TNG.  I think he had the idea before the conference.  Gerhard "Decided Not To Use Klingon" Paseman, 2020.06.07.

Comment: I've asked J-P. Serre about the invention of the term magma: his answer is "*Il me semble que c'est Bourbaki qui a inventé ça. Autant que je souvienne, il voulait un mot qui n'ait pas été déjà utilisé en algèbre, et qui suggère quelque chose n'ayant aucune structure intéressante. Je crois que nous avions pensé à "fourbi", mais nous l'avons rejeté. En tout cas ça n'a rien à voir avec Ore.*" English rough translation: "*I think Bourbaki invented this. As far as I know, he wanted a word not yet used in algebra, suggesting something that has no interesting structure.* (...)

Comment: (...) *I think we thought of "fourbi" but we rejected it. In any case it's unrelated to Ore*"

Comment: @YCor Thanks for thi comment. Since I learned the word "magma" I intuitively thought of it as a kind of primordial chaos. I was appalled by the explanation in this answer, and I'm glad to know that it's not true.

Comment: The m-word sounds like an awful mockery of a name whether or not it is related to Ore. Also, “something that has no interesting structure” (primordial chaos) completely misses the point: Bourbaki, in their infinite wisdom, were apparently unaware that algebraists are not so much interested in the class of *all* groupoids (there is not much to say about it in this generality, and what is there to say also applies to algebras in other signatures), but they usual study varieties of groupoids satisfying this or that additional identity, precisely because they *do* have interesting structure.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek "magma" is a respectable geologic term which is not considered there as offensive or not pejorative whatsoever, so your superlatives are somewhat exaggerated. If Bourbaki gave them a name, this means they thought it was worth a name. As regards groupoids, I remember spending hours (I don't exaggerate) trying to figure out what a groupoid on 1 generator is, before I learnt that it was just used to mean a magma (I understood it in the meaning of small category with inverses).

Comment: @YCor I can't say I understand the point of your anecdote, but note that it's fairly common that the same word is used in different meanings in different fields, and if you want to read papers in some field, it sure helps to first make oneself familiar with standard terminology in that field. This is not going to be helped by Bourbaki inventing a new word and trying to impose it from outside on practitioners in the field.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek What makes you believe anybody wants to impose a new word? It was created and "binar" also was, as far as I understand. I don't believe anyway that some subcommunity is owner of the terminology. For sure the fact that "groupoid" was mainly used for another meaning was a good reason to create a new one. Searching MO questions with "groupoids" yields 370 answers and if I'm correct, the totality of the 50 first answers points to the "small category" meaning. The point of my anecdote is that using without notice "groupoid" in a (now) rare meaning can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

No this class is not finitely axiomatzable. It can be easily proved by standard methods.

**Update 1.** For non-specialists. One can use the much stronger result from Gaĭnov, A. T.
Power associative algebras over a field of finite characteristic.
Algebra i Logika 9 1970 9–33. Gainov proved that if $F$ is a field of prime characteristic (say, $F_p$) then the variety of all power associative $F$-algebras is not finitely axiomatizable (note that for characterstic 0 Albert's result from 1948 shows that the variety is finitely based). This means that for every $n$ there exists an associativity identity $u=v$ in one variable  and an $F$-algebra $S$ which satisfies all asdociativity identities of length $\le n$ but does not satisfy $u=v$. The multiplicative magma of $S$ has the same property because the identities do not involve additions. Thus the variety of power associative magmas (which the OP calls *binars* for some unknown reasons) is not finitely based.

Comment: Could you elaborate? At present this answer isn't very useful.

Comment: @NoahScweber: I added an update. Do you understand  now?

Comment: "My answer appeared 30 min earlier than the other one" Yes, but until 22 minutes ago -  significantly *after* the other answer - your answer merely consisted of the first two sentences. So that's rather disingenuous.

Comment: Re: terminology, I'd never seen it before but apparently "binar" is indeed occasionally used as a synonym for "magma" in some places; e.g. it's mentioned as an alternate term in [Romanowska/Smith](https://books.google.com/books?id=v5ZIDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=binar&f=false), and actively used in [Jipsen](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24771-5_15) and [Fussner/Jipsen](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.01615.pdf). It does seem to be quite rare though.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why do people keep inventing new names (like "magma" and "binar") for what used to be called "groupoids"? "Binar" at least makes some sense, "magma" seems totally random.

Comment: @bof: The notion of groupoid has been hijacked by category theorists.  "Magma" has been used for the last 20 years, I have not seen "binar" before.

Comment: Are you sure that the other answer is incorrect? I believe it only has a terminological problem - namely, I think @YCor just says "relator" instead of "identity". If you read "identity" instead of "relator" in that answer, does anything remain incorrect there?

Comment: Concerning terminology (@bof) - the way I see it it is more complicated than mere hijacking. The term "groupoid" was introduced by Brandt in 1927 (see e. g. in [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Brandt+groupoid)), and it meant indeed a single binary but *partial* operation which is moreover *associative*, has *units* and *inverses*. And, his partiality was such that it coincided with partiality that occurs in the composition of morphisms in (modern "hijacked") groupoids.

Comment: In my opinion, it was not adequate to use Brandt's terminology for *totally* defined *nonassociative* and *nonunital* things *without inverses*. Brandt, I believe, meant that his beasts were "like partial groups", and this resemblance essentially included inverses, associativity and units, while "oid" was because of partiality.

Comment: You're claiming that my answer is false because I'm not considering the right magma. No, I mean the free object in $V_n$ (that's why I wrote $y$ for the letter in the identity and $x$ the generator of the magma). So in $M_n$ I really mean all relators, e.g. in $V_3$ relators include not only $(xx)x=x(xx)$, but also $((xx)(xx))(xx)=(xx)((xx)(xx))$, etc, i.e., obtained from relating identities by replacing $y$ by an arbitrary word in $x$. I wrote "varieties generated by relators..." because I think of it as relators and it generates with the rules of varieties, including substitution.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე:  The other answer is incorrect. The deduction  of identities is not the same as deduction of relations. YCor proves that the 1-gen free power assoxiative magma is not finitely presented. It is weaker than what is needed. As I said, it is easy to fix. Most important papers in Universal Algebra where groupoids are used call it groupoids. You can look it up. Malcev, McKenzie and others in 1970-2000 never used other terminology. Brandt groupoids are Brandt groupoids, a different things.

Comment: The two different usages of groupoids is well-entrenched, and unlikely to go away.  Brandt's original definition is much closer to the category-theoretic definition, so it's definitely not true that they hijacked the universal-algebraic definition, but the UA definition is almost as old.  If UAists want to spontaneously change to "magma" or "binar", then that's fine, but you sometimes see an attempt to impose a name change from the outside, which is unlikely to work.

Comment: @YCor Could you please somehow relate your terminology to the commonly used one? You now also have "relating identities", what does this exactly correspond to in standard terminology? Or you may keep yours but then rigorously define what does it mean exactly. E. g. identities can be equivalently described (I believe) using substitution-closed congruences on free algebras (in general you need infinitely-generated free algebras for that, maybe not here), is this what you mean by relating identities?

Comment: @user158834 Concerning terminology: do you agree with the version of history of the term "groupoid" in the [Wikipedia article about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra))?

Comment: @arsmath I once attended a conference (in Berkeley, sometime in the nineties) aimed at reconciling the UA and CT communities. I would say it was a disaster.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm sorry I'm not familiar with "commonly used" terminology (if any); in any case I can't imagine any other sensible meaning to "variety generated by the relating identities (...)" other than the relevant one. Namely, given a set $X$ of "relating identities" (a set of equalities between elements of free magmas, e.g. $\{x(yz)\equiv (xy)z,xy\equiv yx\}$), by "the variety generated (defined?) by the relating identities $X$" I mean the collection of all magmas in which all these identities hold.

Comment: @user158834 No, you're misreading my answer. Indeed $M_n$ is the free 1-generated element in the variety, and is not defined by a finite presentation as you want to believe ($M_n$ is probably not finitely presented but this is something else). If $R$ is a magma equivalence relation in the free magma on $k$ generators $B_k$ and $R$ is a strictly increasing union of $R_n$ with each $B_k/R_n$ a relatively free magma (= free in some variety), then $B_k/R$ is not finitely axiomatizable as variety of magmas.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე It's a lost opportunity.  They fit together naturally (and one doesn't subsume the other).

Comment: @YCor Oh I see. So then I am sure the established terminology for these is simply identities. No need to add "relating".

Comment: @YCor Regarding your next comment - every finitely generated free algebra is trivially finitely presented in its variety (using the presentation having empty set of relations).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე the problem is that "identity" doesn't provide the distinction between "relators" and "relations" which I find particularly useful in practice. I never asked whether free algebras are f.p., I meant $M_n$ which in my post denotes not a free magma, but some relatively free magma on 1 generator, defined by an infinite presentation. It's probably not finitely presented for $n\ge 3$.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, I understand better now. I guess it is very rare that free algebras of subvarieties are finitely presentable in the larger variety. And as you said this is not relevant here anyway.